# How to open new ejs file after clicking the button?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am creating one form in which after clicking submit i want to open another ejs page.right now i am not able to do that.I am putting my 2nd file in action in app.js.

app.js

```
app.get('/form1', function (req, res) {
    res.render('form', {
        title: "Login", 
        action: "/form1", 
        fields: [
            { name: 'Name', type: 'text', property: 'required' },
            { name: 'Email', type: 'text', property: 'required' }
            { name: 'Phone No', type:'text', property: 'required' }
        ]
    });
});
```

The ejs file is given below

form1.ejs

```
<form action="<%= action %>" method="post">
    <% if (fields.length) { %>
        <% fields.forEach(function(field) { %>
            <label><%= field.name %></label>
            <input type="<%= field.type %>" name="<%= field.name %>"
                <% if (field.property) { %>
                    <%= field.property %>
                <% } %>
            >
        <% }) %>
    <% } %>
    <button type="submit"><%= title %></button> <!-- Title for button is same as that of the page -->
</form>
```

the 2nd file which i want to open after clicking submit button.

```
<form action="<%= action %>" method="post">
    <h> Data goes here </h>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
app.post('/form1', function (req, res) {
    //Do wherever you want here like fetching data and show from the previous form.
    res.render('form2', {
        title: "Show", 
        fields: [
            { name: 'Name', type: 'text', property: 'required' },
            { name: 'Email', type: 'text', property: 'required' }
            { name: 'Phone No', type:'text', property: 'required' }
        ]
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another route (POST) for form1 (first ejs page/form)

```
app.post('/form1', function (req, res) {
    // Do the task with the form data submitted
    // Redirect to form2/file 2
    res.redirect(URL_to_second_form or file2);
}
```

Now, when the user click submit on form1 page, it will automatically open second ejs page or file 2.